# Увидел в тексте слово "что" с отмеченным ударением, зачем это было нужно?

Tags: орфография, орфоэпия

"Подлежит ли вообще «предание» определению, или же как все, **чтó** есть «жизнь», оно «превосходит всякий ум», и вернее было бы его не определять, а описывать." – это из книги В. Н. Лосского.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, ударение может ставиться для того, чтобы избежать двоякого прочтения:

*Он знал, что есть жизнь* (что жизнь существует).

*Он  знал, **чтó** есть жизнь* (что такое жизнь).

В вашем примере, полагаю, автор хотел выделить слово интонационно внутри фразы:

*или же как все, **чтó** есть «жизнь», оно «превосходит всякий ум»*

Ср. без ударения на «что»: *или же как все, что есть **«жизнь»**, оно «превосходит всякий ум»*.